# Are macros the only way to force inline

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a class member function which is the critical path in my application. It must be as fast as possible for my application to deliver the expected (read: rather the hoped) overall performance.

The function is rather complex but have nearly identical sections repeated several times. Something like:

```
if (condition)
{
    //... some code
}
if (another condition}
{
    //... nearly identical code which may change condition
}
if (condition)
{
    //... some code (same as above)
}

// and so on
```

In order to make the code easier to read, understand and maintain I like to break it down and use function calls instead. Like:

```
if (condition)
{
    some_function(some_param);
}
if (another condition}
{
    some_function(some_other_param);
}
if (condition)
{
    some_function(some_param);
}
```

I can't afford any overhead calling functions so I like to make sure that `some_function` is inlined - always.

I searched SO and read several post discussing similar issues but not exactly the same. These post indicates that the only way are `macro`.

I will hate to use `macros` but on the other hand I also hate the complexity of my current function. It is like choosing between two evils.

Is it so? Are macros the only way to achieve this?

**Update**

I got a lot good feedback (thanks).

Nearly all answers suggest that I shall not worry/care about forcing function calls to be inline as the compiler will do *the best* for me anyway.

So I decided to go for it and make a test. I rewrote the code to use function calls whenever code snippets could be reused and ended up with a much more readable (and maintainable) version.

Then I tested the new code and the old code with 100 test runs and calculated the performance as an average. In average the performance of the new version was ~1% (a little less .. 0.88%) lower than the old code. So there was a performance hit. On the other hand - the performance hit was not as high as I expected.

My conclusion is that I prefer the new code as it is much easier to understand. This also means easier to maintain, debug and hand-over to others. Then I'll have to find the lost performance by a gain in some other code block.

Oh, the last thing - which answer to accept? I really don't know. All answers have been helpful input. But only two answers actually address the original question. To me they seem equally good so I'll take the one posted first.

Comment: Under msvc there is `__forceinline` attribute, but I have no idea if it actually forces inlining. You can look at assember output and check if your function really gets inlined. Anyway, I'd recommend avoiding macros.

Comment: There is the inline keyword, but generally the compiler just laughs at you when it sees this. The compiler is very good at inlining when it needs to

Comment: force inline may be used (compiler specific). But it is not necessary better performance to inline anyway. Compiler do generally a better job than human guess.

Comment: There is no portable way to force a function to be inlined.  If it must be inlined the only portable way I know is to use a macro.

Comment: @Jarod42 - `And not necessary better performance to inline anyway` Hmm... Sounds strange but interesting. Any examples, guidelines or other information you could share?

Comment: How have you determined that you "can't afford any overhead calling functions"? Have you profiled your code and found this to be a problem?

Comment: Whether inlining is faster depends on a number of factors, foremost the frequency with which the function is being called and the size of the function. The compiler does a good job of deciding this, which is why Joel suggests only optimizing if you're profiled and determined this is a place you need to make an optimization.

Comment: With inlined code, the code is bigger, you have to retrieve more cache line for code, whereas you may reuse previous function cache line for the function call. Compiler may also inline differently.

Comment: @Jarod42 - see you point with regard to cache. The function is however not that big - complex but not huge.

Comment: @4386427, if that is the case, the compiler will most likely inline it for you.

Comment: @JoelCornett - Please provide an example showing that function calls are better than inline when it comes to performance. I really like to see that so that I can understand whether it is applicable to my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @4386427, it's the other way around: you want to incur in the cost of forcing the inlining of the functions, so _you_ have to prove that it will, effectively, improve your performance. Performance is typically, IME, more connected to algorithmic efficiency than critical-path-function-calls.

Comment: @4386427 just measure the performance with the "ugly big function" versus the one with the function calls and see if you have any statistically relevant improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a macro would be the only *guaranteed* way to get inlined code.

You could also declare a C++ function using the `inline` keyword. That has some implications in terms of scoping, but with most compilers it's also a hint that the compiler should try to generate the the function's code inline with the caller.

Whether or not your compiler will do that, is a separate issue. It may or may not also require enabling certain compilation optimization options.

You should try compiling `inline` functions, then examining the resulting code to see if the compiler inlined the function calls for you.

Answer (score 3):

Believe it or not, there are sometime circumstances where a function call winds up being *faster* than having the code inlined.

So I recommend writing the functions in such a way that the compiler can see the function body at the point of call in your `if` statements, optionally mark the functions inline, and then let the compiler determine if it's better to inline the call or not.

THEN what you do is profile the code (or possibly examine the generated assembly) and see where your hotspots are. If it shows specifically the call-in to your functions as hot, then you have to resort to the macro approach. Note that if you do fall back on the macro make sure you profile again and that it really did help. Compilers are getting really good at optimization.

Comment: Well - must admit that I found it difficult to imagine a case where `inlining` is slower than function calls - I love to see an example if you have one. Regarding - profiling... all ready done and (as expected) this function is the critical path. It'll take like 4-5 days to redo that profiling with another code base but maybe I should give it a try.

Comment: Check the code generated by your compiler before making any unnecessary changes.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler isn't randomly/arbitrarily going to not-inline your `static inline ...` functions, it's going to do it for fairly smart reasons.

For example:

```
if (n == 1) {
    n = 2;
    // more lines of code
}
if (y == 1) {
    // 200 lines of code
}
```

This compiles to something like (pseudo assembly)

```
  cmp n, 1
  bne end_if_1
  mov 2, n
  // ...
end_if_1:
  cmp y, 1
  bne end_if_2
  // result of 200 lines of cod
```

That is, you branch whenever the condition is false, when n is not equal to 1, because the function is inlined so the next instruction is from inside the `if`s scope.

In some cases "not inlined" simply means that the compiler stored the code for a function outside the main body of the function or someplace other than where in the logical sequence it was written. It doesn't automatically imply a heavy weight function call, the instructions are just not where you would expect them to be if the inline was happening trivially.

```
  cmp n, 1
  bne end_if_1
  mov 2, n
  // ...
end_if_1:
  cmp y, 1
  beq outlined_chunk_1 // <<<<
end_if_2:
  cmp ...
// ...
// rest of the function
// ...
  ret

outlined_chunk_1:
  // ... result of 200 lines of code
oc1_ret:
  jmp end_if_2
```

So continue writing your code as `static inline` private helper functions, profile, and look for a forced-inline mechanism as and when you find the compiler has clearly misjudged and is costing you significant perf.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers use a scoring technique when deciding whether to inline a candidate function. The `inline` keyword has a small impact on that score. With gcc, there are a number of command line options that will tweak the scoring:

```
-finline-limit
-fmax-inline-insns-single
-fmax-inline-insns-auto
```

My suggestion would be, as suggested above, first see if the compiler is actually inlining your function. If it is, leave it. Compilers are good at this and you should only intervene if you are not getting what you want. If it isn't, and you're using gcc, you can next try tweaking the above options.

If none of those things work, and to answer your question, yes, macros are the only way to force inlining, even on MSVC which has `__forceinline`. Even so, do everything possible to avoid using them.

Comment: I can't check whether it is `inline`d for every build as we do 8-10 builds a day.  Consequently, I need control of front.

Comment: I understand, but still disagree. There are many optimizations that would cause performance issues in your application if the compiler failed to do them. You can't control for all of them, and this is actually one of the more predictable ones. Good luck regardless.

Answer (score 0):

If using `inline` for functions be careful that the compiler can automatically make large functions or functions containing loops to be not inline.

The safest bet is to use `#define` macro to force the compiler to inline the function.

Comment: You're making a bet with respect to maintainability and debuggability of your code. Whether the output of the compiler is optimal is something you don't have to bet on. You can see it for yourself. Don't optimize if the compiler is already doing the right thing.

Comment: Okay so compromise speed with asthetics eh?

Comment: Maintainabillity and debuggability are not aesthetic things, they are some of the most practical items on your priority list when you are developing production code. I am not suggesting any compromise on performance here.

Comment: Okay so how does using #define or inlining a function make code less debuggable or maintainable?

Comment: A macro knows no scope, and a macro is not type safe.

Comment: @AdamLeggett - true, true, true... but what is the better approach? If it is none, none, none - then this may be the best answer!

Comment: The better approach is to write your method and mark it `inline`. Profile your application during development; you should get the results you want. If you encounter a performance regression in a future build, profile it again at that point.